# Spring Batch Metadata Connection Debugging

Tags: spring-batch, spring-jdbc

We are periodically getting an error in our application when Spring Batch is attempting to get a connection to the metadata tables. It seems that we have a leak somewhere or somehow that is not releasing or closing connections.

What I am looking for is some way to have Spring Batch log when it is getting a connection from the pool, releasing a connection back to the pool, etc. Then we can attempt to determine where our leak is.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see that by enabling debug logs for `org.springframework.jdbc`. Otherwise you can use a tool like [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy).